Adding a field from a table into the body of an automated email
I'm trying to add a field to the body of an email sent out to customers, so that the name
of the customer appears within the body. The string in the field will vary depending on the order.
Instead of the email starting with 'Dear Customer,' would start with 'Dear Jane Bennett,' for salesnumber 1
would start with 'Dear John Wickham,' for salesnumber 2, etc.
Adding a snippet of the relevant code below.
from My_Modules.core_modules import SendEmail, SetEnvironment, GetSQLConnection, ExecuteSQLFile, ComposeEmail 
import sys 
import os 
import re

class main:
def GetOrders():

    Sales = list()

    fields = ['ponum', 'salesnumber', 'Name', 'CustEmail']

    with GetSQLConnection(env['server'], env['database'], Logger) as conn:

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        R, C, I = ExecuteSQLFile(env['Dirs']['Queries'], 'Shipped.sql', (), cursor, Logger)

        if len(R) == 0:
            Logger.debug('No new orders.')
            sys.exit()

    for r in R:
        
        record = tuple([r[I.index(x)] for x in fields])

        Sales.append(record)

    return Sales, fields

def WriteEmailBody(o, f):

    body = """<p><i>Dear Customer,</i></p>
    
    <p><i>This message serves to notify you that your order has shipped.  
    Please keep an eye on your email PO <b>%s</b>  for shipping updates.</i></p>
    """ % o[f.index('ponum')]

    body += "<p><i>CS</i></p>"

    return body


Try changing Customer to %s and including the appropriate variable in the conversion specifier. I guess that would be % (o[f.index('name')], o[f.index('ponum')]) .

You just need to add another variable in your mailmerge code.
You didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, so the code below is untested. I'm assuming you have
the Name variable like you have ponum.
You can add another %s instead of "Customer". This means to insert a string in
that spot. The whole mechanism is printf style string interpolation from the C language's printf function.
After the string you add a % and the variables to interpolate, in the order
of the %s in the string. In this case the name is in the salutation, so it
goes first.
def WriteEmailBody(o, f):

    body = """<p><i>Dear %s,</i></p>
    
    <p><i>This message serves to notify you that your order has shipped.  
    Please keep an eye on your email PO <b>%s</b>  for shipping updates.</i></p>
    """ % (o[f.index('Name')], o[f.index('ponum')])

    body += "<p><i>CS</i></p>"

    return body

Making sure the %s and the variables line up can be a bit tedious, and if you
mess up, the compiler won't notice and you just get the wrong text interpolated.
You can avoid this with f strings where
the string is prefixed with an f and the variables are inside the string in
curly braces:
def WriteEmailBody(o, f):

    body = f"""<p><i>Dear {o[f.index('Name')]},</i></p>

    <p><i>This message serves to notify you that your order has shipped.
    Please keep an eye on your email PO <b>{o[f.index('ponum')]}</b>  for shipping updates.</i></p>
    """
    body += "<p><i>CS</i></p>"

    return body

